# Xamarin.Forms SetBinding to Image so that it refreshes when its Source changes

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bindable

I am trying to have images in my page update / re-draw when I change their ImageSource - this will help me have them re-load async.

I thought having a bindable property for the imageSource bound to the image was a start, but it is not updating the image. I have tried a large number of ways including a viewModel approach with an OnPropertyChanged event, but I don't think I quite understood this.

This binding also has to be done in code, this is just how the app is written (minimal xaml).

So far my general approach has been:

Bindable property

`public static readonly BindableProperty ImageFileProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ImageProperty", typeof(string), 
            typeof(CustomImageClass));`

`public string ImageProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(ImageFileProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ImageFileProperty, value);
            }
        }`

Inside the CustomImageClass constructor:

`this.SetBinding(ImageFileProperty, "ImageProperty");`

From here I would like to to have the image change when I update the ImageSource and have the image change. I hope this is specific enough, I think all the different examples bound to the xaml have confused me in how I need to do it in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sorry the poor english

I guess there's a lot of problem here...

If I understand well, you wanna create a BindableProperty in your CustomImageClass. Is that right?
If yes, so you can use the default convention to the bindable property name's, like this (note that I changed the type too):

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ImageFileProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ImageFile", typeof(ImageSource), 
        typeof(CustomImageClass));

public ImageSource ImageFile
{
    get{ return (string)GetValue(ImageFileProperty); }
    set{ SetValue(ImageFileProperty, value); }
}
```

You can't to set bind to this property you've just create in your constructor. This will be used  when you're consuming the class (in xaml or c#).

Now you have to use your property to set the image where you wanna show. I think you should have a variable or private property in this class that is of Image type, for example 'image', so, inside the constructor you should do

```
image = new Image();
image.BindingContext = this;
image.SetBinding(Image.Source, nameof(ImageFile));
```

Let me know if I missunderstood, please.
I hope that helps you.

Comment: Great thanks Diego! No your explanation in English is fine.

I was not adding the BindingContext correctly in which you have pointed out the correct way for me. This works fine for me now.
Another thing to note for someone not getting expected results with the PropertyBindings - my images were not changing correctly for me when trying to get this code working originally but after both a clean and full removing of the app from the test device the images returned to normal. Possible caching type issues.